# Docker runtime metrics in boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

As stated in [this document](https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/runmetrics/), docker container's runtime matrix should be available at `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/lxc/<longid>/`.

However, if I am using boot2docker image, I can only find a folder named docker under `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/` with some matrices.

```
$ ls /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/ -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 cgroup.clone_children
--w--w--w-    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 cgroup.event_control
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 cgroup.procs
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 cgroup.sane_behavior
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 Mar 25 07:41 docker/
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.failcnt
--w-------    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.force_empty
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.failcnt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.limit_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.max_usage_in_bytes
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.slabinfo
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.tcp.failcnt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.tcp.limit_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.tcp.max_usage_in_bytes
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.tcp.usage_in_bytes
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 04:00 memory.limit_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.max_usage_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.memsw.failcnt
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 04:00 memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.move_charge_at_immigrate
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.oom_control
----------    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.pressure_level
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 04:00 memory.soft_limit_in_bytes
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.stat
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.swappiness
-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.usage_in_bytes
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 memory.use_hierarchy
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 notify_on_release
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 release_agent
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Mar 25 08:39 tasks
```

How can I get back the missing LXC matrices in boot2docker image?